# Homotopy groups of finite CW complex finitely generated as Lie algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, whitehead-product

This is probably a well-known question, but I haven't found the answer on MO or MSE.

It is well-known that the homotopy groups of a finite CW complex $X$ need not be finitely presented, even as $\mathbf Z[\pi_1(X)]$-module (see for instance Exercise 38 in §4.2 of Hatcher). The first counterexamples are constructed using the graded quasi-Lie algebra structure on $\pi_{\geq 2}(X) := \bigoplus_{i\geq 2} \pi_i(X)$ coming from the Whitehead product, leaving the following question:

**Question.** *If $X$ is a finite connected CW complex, is every finite truncation $\pi_{[2,r]}(X) := \pi_{\geq 2}(X)/\pi_{>r}(X)$ finitely generated as graded quasi-Lie algebra over $\mathbf Z[\pi_1(X)]$?*

Clearly we can only hope for this truncated version, as each prime appears eventually in the order of $\pi_i(S^2)$. I have found versions of the above for rational homotopy groups, but this version also seems plausible to me.

Comment: (I'm not even sure about the precise compatibility between the $\pi_1(X)$-action on $\pi_{\geq 2}(X)$ and the Whitehead bracket, so maybe "quasi-Lie algebra over $\mathbf Z[\pi_1(X)]$" does not literally make sense. But I mean that you're allowed to apply both the $\pi_1(X)$-action and the Whitehead bracket on your generators, in any order you like.)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: what are versions of this after rationalization?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is finite and the Goodwillie tower of the identity converges at $X$, then there is a filtration of $X$ with associated graded equivalent to $\Omega^\infty \mathrm{Free}_\mathrm{lie}(\Sigma^\infty X)$. In this sense, the homotopy of $X$ is smaller than the homotopy of the free Lie algebra of a finite spectrum which is a homotopical analogue of the finiteness you want. The homology of these free Lie algebras is well understood by Behrens, Kjaer, and Konovalov, but I imagine the homotopy is quite unknown, though this is basically the point of https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1125 .

Comment: Of course I should mention [Arone-Mahowald](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050300) in the above comment, though I have not read much of the paper so I can't say too much.

Comment: @Z.M hmm, I found something earlier today about that, but didn't check it carefully, and I can't seem to find it again at the moment. Maybe it had additional hypotheses that make it trivial (e.g. simply connected, where the result is even true integrally)...

Comment: @ConnorMalin the Behrens paper you cite never mentions the word Lie at all. It seems that what you say could be an answer (to a question I didn't ask but maybe should have?), so I would be grateful if you could provide some more details.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. Section 1 of the Behrens paper computes the $\mathbb{F}_2$ Dyer-Lashof algebra of the Lie operad which is equivalently $\partial_* \mathrm{Id}$. The Kjaer paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06605 shows an analogous set of generators exists for general $\mathbb{F}_p$. The Konovalov paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.06240 shows (Theorem F) analogous relations hold in the case of $\mathbb{F}_p$. The Arone-Mahowald paper, the earliest of all these, shows that the many homotopy operations of Lie algebras vanish.

Comment: Lastly, I don't necessarily think this is the "correct" version of your question, but I think it might lead one to find situations where your question has a positive answer. For instance, maybe having the Goodwillie tower of the identity converge is enough of a requirement to ensure the algebraic statement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Ian Leary's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/300736) gives a counterexample. His construction shows that for every $k\ge 2$ there exists a group $G_k$, and a finite $k$-dimensional CW complex $X$ such that $\pi_1(X)=G_k$, $\pi_i(X)=0$ for $1<i<k$, and $\pi_k(X)$ is not finitely generated as a module over $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$. But then $\pi_{[2,k]}(X)$ can not be finitely generated as a quasi Lie algebra over $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$.

On the other hand, if $X$ is a nilpotent finite complex, then $\pi_i(X)$ is a finitely generated group for all $i$ (see "More concise algebraic topology", Theorem 4.5.2) and it follows that $\pi_{[2,k]}(X)$ is finitely generated as a quasi Lie algebra. The Goodwillie tower of the identity does converge for nilpotent spaces, so this ties in with Connor's comments.

Comment: Ah, this does seem to give a counterexample. Because the indexing is off by one compared to that answer, I think this only settles $k \geq 3$, right? I am actually also interested in $k=2$; do you happen to know if there might be a positive result in that case?

Comment: I think Ian's answer gives a counterexample for $k = 2$, no? This is also discussed in Andreas Thom's answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100155/second-homotopy-group-of-cayley-complex where examples of presentation complexes of finitely presented groups with non-finitely generated $\pi_2$ are given.